# Strategy for adding UILabel or text above table view rows

Tags: uitableview, uilabel

I have a list of "answers" which I'm displaying in a UITableView, which is contained by a UIView. I'd like to add a label above it for the "question". I've tried adding a UILabel to the UIView, above the UITableView but am having difficulty with it, as when I initialize it, the text doesn't display and the list disappears (it is connected to the view). My question is, 1) is this the best strategy? and 2) how to implement this - a pointer to some sample code would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the UITableView docs, there's a tableViewHeader property which looks to do the trick.

Also, a way to slick up the table interface, including the header, is described here:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html